# Mutating Admission Controller doesnt get called on Deployments Create/Updates

Tags: kubernetes

I have a ValidatingWebhookConfiguration monitoring Pods which is working fine. I also have a MutatingWebhookConfiguration monitoring ( and eventually mutating ) Deployment Objects.

I have both the Controllers written in Go. Pretty much the code for Mutating one  is a clone of the Validating one.

On the ValidatingWebhookConfiguration the triggering rule is :

```
 - operations: ["CREATE","UPDATE"]
   apiGroups: [""]
   apiVersions: ["v1"]
   resources: ["pods"]
```

It is getting triggered fine.

On the MutatingWebhookConfiguration the triggering rule is :

```
 - operations: ["CREATE","UPDATE"]
   apiGroups: [""]
   apiVersions: ["v1beta1"]
   resources: ["deployments"]
```

I am able to see that the webhook is getting started, but I am not getting it to trigger.

I have tried changing `v1beta1` to `extensions/v1beta1` and still have no luck.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong ?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,

-Sreeni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take action on deployments, you need to specify the api group.
For deployments it is `apps`.
You can get a list of all resources in kubernetes and the according api groups with the following command:

```
$ kubectl api-resources        
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIGROUP                       NAMESPACED   KIND
bindings                                                                      true         Binding
...
deployments                       deploy       apps                           true         Deployment
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me. I had to add : apiGroups: ["apps","extensions"].  Then it worked, now at least I am seeing that its making connections.

Comment: Great that it worked out! Since Kubernetes 1.9 deployments have been migrated to apps/v1, the older versions are deprecated. I suggest to update your manifests accordingly. (If you have a k8s >= 1.9 )

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Yes. We are on 1.14. This brought it to our notice and are working towards moving over.